# File scanning - nextLine method

Tags: java

there is a part of my program, in which I have a problem. I want to have letters written from a file. The file contains some letters and numbers, each of them in a separate line. (I need only "P","O" and "W" letters) I don't understand why the program doesn't output the letters. Code and the image of file below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZCtq.jpg

```
File file = new File("file.txt");
        Scanner in;
        try {
            in = new Scanner(file);

            while (in.hasNextLine())
            {
                if(in.nextLine() == "W" || in.nextLine() == "O" || in.nextLine() == "P")
                {
                    System.out.println(in.nextLine());
                }
            }


            in.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is skipping checking some lines. Every time when you calling `in.nextLine()` it will read the second line.

Try this way

```
File file = new File("file.txt");
    Scanner in;
    try {
        in = new Scanner(file);

        while (in.hasNextLine())
        {
           String MyLine = in.nextLine();
            if(MyLine.equals( "W") || MyLine.equals( "O") || MyLine.equals(  "P"))
            {
                System.out.println(MyLine);
            }
        }


        in.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [string.equals(Object obj)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) method to compares strings. 
Operator == just compare references, but does not check the actual contents of the strings.

And in this line

```
if(in.nextLine() == "W" || in.nextLine() == "O" || in.nextLine() == "P")
```

you get new line every time, you call in.nextLine() method

Answer (score 0):

I fixed Your code:

```
    File file = new File("file.txt");
    Scanner in;
    try {
        in = new Scanner(file);

        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            String tmp = in.nextLine();
            if (tmp.equals("W") || tmp.equals("O") || tmp.equals("P")) {
                System.out.println(tmp);
            }
        }

        in.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

1). Allways use method [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method for comparing Strings.

2). Method nextLine() should be used once inside loop. Every use of this method reads next line from file.